# How can I generate per user contribution graph in mercurial/tortoise hg?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I want to Check contribution of each user in a mercurial repository. I found Bitbucket Awwsome Graphs, but they are not good.

I have tried hg churn but it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Please refrain from calling things "just dumb". It's not overly polite, and it doesn't explain _why_ the thing didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty simple filter you can access by using the Search function toolbox (Ctrl + S):

```
user(USERNAMEHERE)
```

Execute the filter and you will see the contribution history of the selected user in the repository.

Make sure you have selected the correct branch in your filtered view on the far-right of the toolbar ("★ Show all ★" or otherwise).

**EDIT**- added some screenshots to better explain.

[Before using the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBwrC.png)

[After using the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JIQz.png)

Comment: It won't fulfill my needs. I need some comparing system, please look at Git contribution Graphs to have an idea what I'm looking for.